# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred. Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, .net, indexoutofboundsexception

My code is showing unhandled exception of ArrayIndexOutOfRangeException.

```
    public static DateTime storeTime(String date)
    {
        string[] dateSplit;
        string[] timeSplit;
        DateTime returnValue = new DateTime();

        if (date == "")
            return returnValue;

        dateSplit = date.Split(new Char[] { 'T' });
        timeSplit = dateSplit[1].Split(new Char[] { '+' }); // Exception occurs here.
        timeSplit[0] = timeSplit[0].Substring(0, timeSplit[0].Length - 1);
        returnValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateSplit[0] + " " + timeSplit[0], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",null);

        return returnValue;

    }
```

Comment: It sounds like there is no element on dateSplit[1]... what parameter (date) did u push into your method. May you should debug an look, what's stored into dateSplit, to solve your problem...

Comment: Can you paste `DateTime` class?

Comment: Changed Rohit's edit from [java] to [c#]...correct me if I done smth. wrong

Answer (score 1):

You input parameter `date` did not contain any character T, so your split only resulted in a single element. Trying to access dateSplit[1] (the second element) therefor fails. The index 1 you gave is out of range, only 0 is allowed because there's only one element.

Please note that this is a very basic error and you have probably been voted down because you should be able to detect this by yourself. Next time, press F5 to debug and check all your variables at the point of the crash so you can fix the problem on your own.